# How do I create a queue system that can be modified in execution time while there are processes launched from this queue

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing, queue, execution-time

I want to create a queue system that allows me to enqueue some commands to be executed from the command console. They are neural nets training commands so it will take long to complete them. The problem here is that it needs to be editable in execution time, so that I can enqueue more processes to be launched after the last one on the queue ends. That is needed due to the fact that it takes a lot of time to  train a Neural Network and I would like to be able to waste less time possible and be able to train more than 1 neural network at nighttime.

I have tried some multiprocessing tutorials but none of them have helped me solving this problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to edit the commands after they are issued or do you simply want to add new commands from time to time while the training operation is ongoing?

Comment: I want just add new commands but do not worry, I have found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made up in my mind my solution and it is simpler than I thought.

> **Just use files!.**

If I create a csv with 1 column that is the command I want to execute, I can just make an script to add new commands or rather modify it myself. Then, before I start executing a new command I read the CSV with pandas library, extract the first row, execute that command, remove it when it ends and that's it!